# where is .htaccess in parallel plesk? should I creat it by myself?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I can't find .htaccess in my root and my host provider is not in touch, either I can't change my host and disable my site, because it's about an reward registration.
now I don't know how could I have .htaccess?

for describtion, I want to active gzip for my site...

I researched in some places and didn't find any useful answer for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actualy there should be a file with name `.htaccess` on your server's root folder, sometimes it may be empty and you have to write your commands on it! but if there is not, and if your host gave you privilege, you can creat one...